# Is it possible to run TestNG integration-tests in a Jetty container with JNDI's and spring context?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jetty, testng

I have Maven + Failsafe + Jetty configuration described here: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html.

My Jetty configuration for local development defined in XML file with some JNDIs as described here: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/using-jetty-jndi.html.

**Is it possible to run TestNG tests inside a Jetty container (environment) so that I have access to all JNDI and Spring context my war (application) has access to?**

It seems to me that tests are always executed in some kind of isolated evironment which requires it's own setup, but if that's the case, it seems really meaningless to run Jetty in the first place. Except maybe those cases when I need to make some HTTP calls to test my REST-endpoints, but it's not the case.

Comment: Is this a Spring or Spring Boot app ?

Comment: It's a Spring app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I finally found a way to run my tests with:

1. JNDI context (`InitialContext`) configurated from my Jetty
   Configuration XML.
2. Spring context with some beans, that required those JNDI-resources for initialization.

My goal was to re-use existing web container environment. And as I had no success with "in-container tests", instead of actually running Jetty on pre-integration-test phase, I decided to write my own implementation of [`ContextLoader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextLoader.html) for a [`@ContextConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html).

Here is the general idea of my solution:

```
public class ITestContextLoader extends GenericXmlWebContextLoader {

    @Override
    protected void loadBeanDefinitions(...) { 

        // Initial Context configuration

        Resource jettyXml = Resourse.newSystemResource("jetty-env.xml");
        InputStream resourceStream = jettyXml.getInputStream();
        XmlConfiguration xmlConfig = new XmlConfiguration(resourceStream);

        xmlConfig.configure(); // for some reason it's not only returns 
                               // instance of configured context, but also 
                               // populates InitialContext with JNDI resources


        // Bean definitions loading

        ... 
    }
}
```

It's not the way I saw it or wanted to do it in the first place (when I posted the question), but the closest solution I came up with for the moment. Maybe not the best one, so I would certainly appreciate alternatives, advices and pointers.

Comment: You should go ahead and accept your answer, so that the question gets closed.